# Angular2 pipe not functioning as desired

Tags: angular

I have created a pipe to search a table based on ID. This is the sample JSON i am using to populate tables

```
[
  {
    "id": "59247cd5a05cfa4966af706d",
    "lease": {
       "client": {
          "client_id": 1,
          "client_name": "Test Client 1",
          "date_added": "2017-05-12T07:13:46.197000"
       },
       "lease_id": 293,
       "user_modified": "system"
    }
  }
]
```

Can someone point out the mistake in the pipe.?

```
export class SearchPipe implements PipeTransform {
transform(leaseData: any[], filter: any): any {
    if (!leaseData || !filter) {
        return leaseData;
    }

    return leaseData.filter(leaseData => leaseData.id.indexOf(filter.id) !== -1)

}
```

I have called the pipe in the html like this .

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of leaseData | search:filterLease; let i = index ">
```

I want to filter the data based on the ID. But now the entire data disappears whenever i enter a character. filterlease is the model name of the textbox used to search.

```
<input  type="text" id="sampleSearchInput" [(ngModel)]="filterLease" ><i id = "icon-search-mat" class="material-icons">search</i>
```

Comment: What's `filterLease`? Is it a primitive? Is it an object? Also, I can't see the `@Pipe` *decorator*, did you missed it?

Comment: Please add details on what is the functionality that you desire and what you are getting instead.

Answer (score 0):

That's not how the filter method work. It should be

```
return leaseData.filter(element => element.id === filter.id)
```

filter takes a function that is called with every element of the list, and that should return true if the element must be kept in the output. You want to keep the element if it has the same ID as the filter.